# Need to know the difference between contains and items keyword of json schema validation

Tags: python, json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator, python-jsonschema

i am using jsonschema validation library of python to perform the schema validation below are the code snippet used along with the schema version and sample json data. my question is when i am using the **schema version one** where **contains** keyword is used the error response which i get from code snippet is very generic like it does not gives you the element wise validation failure reason but when i use slightly modified version of schema where i am using **items** instead of **contains** the same code snippet gives error in detail at elemenet level.

can someone please explain me, why this is happening or it behaves like this only when using **contains** keyword or i am missing something in my code snippet.

json schema version one:

```html
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema#",
    "type": "array",
    "contains": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "minContains": 2,
    "maxContains": 5
}
```

json schema version two:

```html
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema#",
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "minContains": 2,
    "maxContains": 5
  }
```

json data:

```html
["", "1234"]
```

code snippet:

```html
import json
import jsonschema
from jsonschema import Draft201909Validator
from jsonschema.exceptions import ValidationError


json_file = 'json_schema_validation/sample.json'
json_schema_file = 'json_schema_validation/sample_schemav2.json'


with open(json_file) as f:
    rec = json.load(f)

with open(json_schema_file) as f:
    schema = json.load(f)

  

v = Draft201909Validator(schema)

errors = sorted(v.iter_errors(rec), key=lambda e: e.path)
for error in errors:
    print("---------------------------------------")
    print("json_path list:", list(error.path))
    print("error_message:", error.message)
```

output when used schema version two:

```html
---------------------------------------
json_path list: [0]
error_message: '' is not of type 'number'
---------------------------------------
json_path list: [1]
error_message: '1234' is not of type 'number'
```

output when used schema version one:

```html
---------------------------------------
json_path list: []
error_message: ['', '1234'] does not contain items matching the given schema
```

Answer (score 1):

As per Json Schema documentation,

**Contains** means that at least one item of the array is valid

**Items** means that all elements of the array are valid

https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/array

So it's up to your use-case to determine if you want to validate at least one or everything

Answer (score 1):

From the [JSON Schema reference](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/array#contains), regarding to array validation:

> While the `items` schema must be valid for every item in the array, the `contains` schema only needs to validate against one or more items in the array.

There are some examples on the docs where you can see that the `items` validation restricts the array to have all values compliant with the rule. But in the case of `contains`, only one *valid* value is enough to make it compliant.

This explains why the errors can be detailed in the `items` particular case.